# How to make Jquery DataTable default Search Box to filter minimum column?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I wanted to use Jquery default search box to filter limited column. 
Its predefined state is all columns sortable. How can I use to limit the columns to filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the datatable, you can define columns to be non-searchable like so.

```
$('#table').dataTable(
    "aoColumns": [ 
        {"bSearchable": true},
        {"bSearchable": false}, 
        {"bSearchable": false}
]);
```

So in this case, there would be three columns and only the first one would be searchable.

Comment: No its not working .. If i include this, then its not taking into account that first column only searchable.

Comment: Note: You will need to add a {"bSearchable": true} or a {"bSearchable": false} for every column you have defined. See http://live.datatables.net/ohadux/3/ for usage and working example. In the example, the search box will only filter the Version column.

Comment: @Wulfram what if the column display is dynamic. I have some calculated fields which I don't want to include in search...is it doable in dataTable as above?